# rails running code in FactoryGirl on every rake task, actually on every environment load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, factory-bot

We could not run `rake db:schema:load` on a new machine because somewhere when loading the Rails environment for the rake task a class method was being called that tried to access a table in the db, which obviously did not yet exist.

I found that it was coming from a FactoryGirl definition.

For 2 of the factories we were setting a location_id variable to the world location.id like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :some_model do
    ....
    ....
    cached_location_id Location.world.id
    ....
  end
end
```

so when rails was loading all our code, it was immediately running the `Location.world`. I think this is peculiar to FactoryGirl.

How to solve this?

Comment: Where are your factories located? Nothing in specs should be running during db tasks.

Comment: app/spec/factories/area.rb

app/spec/factories/student.rb

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just change it to only run the Location.world code when the Factory is asked to create the model using `{ }`s like this:

`FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :some_model do
    ....
    ....
    cached_location_id {Location.world.id }
    ....
  end
end`

What a Gotchya!